# Long link is not parsable - Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: url, domain: "nau6x.app.goo.gl")
// other settings
let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
options.pathLength = .short
components.options = option
components.shorten(completion: { (url, warnings, error) in
    if let error = error {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    // handle url
})
```

The app crashes at the `fatalError` line with the following message: "Operation could not be completed. Long link is not parsable"

Comment: I am facing same  problem
"The operation couldn’t be completed. Long link is not parsable: https://wn2d8.app.goo.gl/?link=eMedicoz [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced same situation a while ago. It was the url parameter causing error.

In your first line,

```
let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: url, domain: "nau6x.app.goo.gl")
```

you need to make sure that the "url" must start with "http://" or "https://".
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 19):

I found out that my `uriPrefix` had an `/` at the end which caused a problem on iOS (using Flutter)

Comment: Thanks for this answer: "uriPrefix: 'htps://xxx.xxx.link/',"  to "uriPrefix: 'htps://xxx.xxx.link',"

Comment: @ThirumalGovindaraj https*

Answer (score 0):

I created short link with following code:

```
func createShortUrl(urlString:String){
    guard let link = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    let components = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: "ubg36.app.goo.gl")
    let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
    options.pathLength = .short
    components.options = options
    components.shorten(completion: { (url, warnings, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        print(url?.absoluteString)
    })
}
```

One thing keep in mind that link url should be start with http:// or https://

Hope, It'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on Android. 
Replacing `setDynamicLinkDomain(dynamicLinksDomain)` with `setDomainUriPrefix(dynamicLinksDomain)` when building the link did the trick.